# How to print a List<T> with Criteria?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my simple list:

```
public class ProductStore
  {
      public List<Product> AllProducts
      {
          get
          {
              return new List<Product>
              {
                  new Product{Name = "Stove 1", Category= "Stoves", ID = 1, Price = 99.99},
                  new Product{Name = "Stove 2", Category= "Fireplaces", ID = 2, Price = 139.50},
                  new Product{Name = "Stove 3", Category= "Stoves", ID = 3, Price = 199.99},
                  new Product{Name = "Stove 4", Category= "Stoves", ID = 4, Price = 29.00},
              };
          }

      }
  }
```

An this is how I print these data in View:
    @model List

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AllProducts";
}

<h2>AllProducts</h2>
<ul>
@foreach (var product in Model)
{ 
     <li>Name: @product.Name, Category:@product.Category, Price:@product.Price;</li>
}
</ul>
```

My Question is: What is the best way to print only those element, which have ie. category == Stoves? I know that I can use if statement combined with continue in foreach, but I wonder, is there a smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@foreach (var product in Model.Where(x => x.Category == "Stoves"))`

This is syntactically how you would do it.  But as a programming problem you would probably want to change your design in some way.  You probably want to filter the list before passing it to the view.

You are generating your view based on an MVC controller action.  These actions can take conditional parameters such as query string values like this:

`http://host:12345/Controller/Action?category=Stoves`

This is read as a function parameter in the action and you can use it to return a subset of the actual list:

```
public ActionResult ViewProducts(string category = null)
{
    var products = productStore.AllProducts;

    if (category != null)
        products = products.Where(x => x.Category == category);

    return View(products);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A pure MVC implementation would likely put this in the controller but you could just filter which list of products you loop over with a LINQ query like this...

```
@foreach (var product in Model.AllProducts.Where(p => p.Category == "Stoves").ToList())
{ 
     <li>Name: @product.Name, Category:@product.Category, Price:@product.Price;</li>
}
```

Comment: You probably don't need the `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 3):

Another property that does the filtering would be a good bet.

```
      public List<Product> StoveProducts
      {
          get
          {
              return AllProducts.Where(p => p.Category == "Stoves").ToList();
          }

      }
```